# Is there a method for making Google Chrome open textareas in vim?

Tags: vim, chrome, plugin

I used to use Firefox on a daily basis but have switched to Google Chrome, and have been using it for 2+ years now. The one plugin that I miss is this one, [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/). This plugin allowed for the textarea to be opened into a separate `vim` or `gvim` window where I could do editing and then save the contents when done, back to Firefox.

The closes thing I've found is this plugin is [TextAid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textaid/ppoadiihggafnhokfkpphojggcdigllp?hl=en), but I find it a bit of kludge since it requires a separate web server to be kept up.

I'd really prefer not having to use TextAid, does anyone know of any alternative methods to achieving this using Chrome?

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate for superuser?

Comment: @Patrick - possibly, but I run this entirely on Linux and wanted a Linux slant to it, not windows. Also I know Jasonwryan uses [vimprobable](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2012/11/20/vimprobable/) and I wanted to get feedback as to possible alternatives from other powerusers of this site. If others agree that it's way off topic I'll be happy to move it over to SU, but I frequent that site enough that I wasn't as interested in their take on this at this time.

Answer (score 10):

There is a chrome extension named [Surfingkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/surfingkeys/gfbliohnnapiefjpjlpjnehglfpaknnc), which includes [ACE vim editor](https://ace.c9.io/)(a vim editor implemented with Javascript).

With the extension, you could press `Ctrl-i` to call the vim editor out when you're in a `input` or `textarea` element. Then you could edit your text with the vim editor, and `:wq` to write text in vim editor back to the element on page.

You could also use the vim editor to select option for a `select` element, which is useful when there are tons of options within the `select` element.

More info could be found --
[vim editor with ACE](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys#vim-editor)
.
[image: edit input element]

[image: edit select element]

Comment: Besides this feature, surfingkeys adds a ton of functionality to chrome, not to mention that you can add additional functions using javascript

Comment: Useful plugin, but its vi is not as powerful as firenvim/nvim.

Answer (score 8):

Wasavi opens text areas in a vi-like editor, which is configurable via an `rc` file.

Videos and download links on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi).
Chrome, Opera and Firefox are supported.

Here's an example of me editing this answer:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Update Oct 18:

Try following plugin:

https://github.com/pandysong/ghost-text.vim

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's more difficult with [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) (by design), but you can try [textaid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textaid/ppoadiihggafnhokfkpphojggcdigllp).

See https://superuser.com/questions/261689/its-all-text-for-chrome

Comment: https://github.com/epeli/TextareaConnect is broken so that doesn't look to be a viable option. As I already stated, I'm aware of textaid, wanted alternatives, if any.

Answer (score 3):

Update May 2021:

I know this is an old thread, but for those searching right now, there is a project called [firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim) that exploits the fact that neovim can act as a remote backend to change your textareas to nvim frontends.

In practice it opens nvim directly in your text area like this (image from their page on github):

[image]

Comment: This solution is powerful as it opens a full-fledged vim editor/variant, enabiling use of your system vim config, with some conditionals to load specific config for browser use cases.

Answer (score 2):

In general you have to have a backend. Though, it does not need to be a web server. If you are comfortable with having a script running locally each time you open an *edit* or have a service running (Though that would be close to the issue at hand) it can be done trough using the API to communication with local scripts over pipes.

In short how it works is by using Ajax in the browser. An extension can call a local script which in turn open desired editor and keeps the communication going. The local script prints data to `stdout` and the extension receive what is pushed.

Another choice is to use local storage but have not found a way to  nicely combine it with actually launching local applications.

I have a project on ice using python as backend and primarily Vim as editor, but have also tested it with things like Emacs and Gedit. I had a working version, but mangled it up and have not looked at it for some time.

This is not an answer per se but added it as a note. I might work on the plugin and come back to it ;), but if local script is a non starter I'm afraid it won't help much for your request.

Comment: I'd be interested in where this went if you decide to do something. Please keep me in the loop, I'd be interested in pitching in too if you wanted an extra set of hands.